# run MetaTrader 5 on server (for python)

Tags: python, metatrader4, metatrader5, mt4

I can’t seem to find a solution on how to run MetaTrader 5 on a server like replit.io or etc. The code works on local desktop, but I believe the code on the server can’t initialize mt5. is there a solution for this? running a virtual machine is one expensive solution for this. all I need is to get data and send orders to my metatrader account. 24/7. Thank you in advance!